# Position of Views below self sizing UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have created a `UILabel` which sets the height based on characters. I need to create some `UIImageView`s under the resizable `UILable`. Here is what I did to create the label:

```
let productDescriptionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: imageViewHeight + 10, width: viewWidth - 20, height: 0))
productDescriptionLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
productDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = .right
productDescriptionLabel.text = productsDescriptionArray!
productDescriptionLabel.font = productDescriptionLabel.font.withSize(self.view.frame.height * self.relativeFontConstant)
productDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: productDescriptionLabel.text!)
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 10 
style.minimumLineHeight = 20
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (productDescriptionLabel.text?.characters.count)!))
productDescriptionLabel.attributedText = attrString
productDescriptionLabel.sizeToFit()
productDescriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
contentScrollView.addSubview(productDescriptionLabel)
```

Well I'm wondering what do I define as the `UIImageView` `y:` to make it right below the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you. Create your imageView after label Creation.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: imageViewHeight + 10 + productDescriptionLabel.frame.size.height, width: viewWidth - 20, height: 0))
```